# laravel how can i show the pivot: data from the get() method

Tags: php, database, laravel

when I have the get function I have the following data whats retrieving:

```
{"id":2,"ticketnaam":"testticket2","ticketprijs":"6000","created_at":"2020-03-27
12:50:24","updated_at":"2020-03-27
12:50:24","pivot":{"user_id":2,"ticket_id":2,"tijd":"09:00:00","beschrijving":"test"}}
```

I want to show the pivot items "tijd" and "bechrijving" but when I try to retrieve it it is just showing nothing without any error or something.

my blade:

```
                    <div class="card-body ">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Strippenkaart</th>
                                <th scope="col">Tijd</th>
                                <th scope="col">Beschrijving</th>
                                <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($details as $detail)
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {{$detail->ticketnaam}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{$detail->tijd}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{$detail->beschrijving}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

my user model:

```
    public function tickets(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ticket')->withPivot('tijd','beschrijving');
    }
```

Comment: `detail->pivot->tijd` and `detail->pivot->beschrijving`

Comment: u r welcome....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think can be done like that:

`{{ $detail->pivot->tijd }}`

and

`{{ $detail->pivot->beschrijving }}`

Try so!!

Comment: glad to help :)